# Can't install Ruby 2.0.0 with rvm

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, installation, rvm

I tried to install Ruby 2.0.0 with `rvm install 2.0.0` this was my output:

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p392.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary   rubies.
Installing requirements for osx/10.8/x86_64, might require sudo password
Password:
DEBUG: Copying /Users/Family/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist to      /opt/local/var/macports/home/Library/Preferences
DEBUG: MacPorts sources location: /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
--->  Updating MacPorts base sources using rsync
receiving file list ... done

sent 36 bytes  received 69 bytes  70.00 bytes/sec
total size is 3594240  speedup is 34230.86
receiving file list ... done

sent 36 bytes  received 76 bytes  224.00 bytes/sec
total size is 512  speedup is 4.57
DEBUG: successful verification with key /opt/local/share/macports/macports-pubkey.pem
DEBUG: /usr/bin/tar -C   /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/tmp -xf /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/base.tar
MacPorts base version 2.1.3 installed,
DEBUG: Rebuilding and reinstalling MacPorts if needed
MacPorts base version 2.1.3 downloaded.
--->  Updating the ports tree
Synchronizing local ports tree from rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar
DEBUG: /usr/bin/rsync -rtzv --delete-after   rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
receiving file list ... done

sent 36 bytes  received 70 bytes  212.00 bytes/sec
total size is 55050240  speedup is 519341.89
DEBUG: /usr/bin/rsync -rtzv --delete-after      rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar.rmd160    /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
receiving file list ... done

sent 36 bytes  received 77 bytes  226.00 bytes/sec
total size is 512  speedup is 4.53
DEBUG: successful verification with key /opt/local/share/macports/macports-pubkey.pem
DEBUG: /usr/bin/tar -C /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/tmp -xf /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar
Creating port index in /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports

Total number of ports parsed:   0 
Ports successfully parsed:  0 
Ports failed:           0 
Up-to-date ports skipped:   16692

--->  MacPorts base is already the latest version
DEBUG: Setting MacPorts sources ownership to root

The ports tree has been updated. To upgrade your installed ports, you should run
port upgrade outdated
Missing required packages: autoconf, automake, libtool, pkg-config, libiconv, libyaml, libffi, readline, libxml2, libxslt, libksba, openssl, curl-ca-bundle, sqlite3, zlib, ncurses, gdbm.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/Family/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392, this may take a       while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p392, this may take a while depending on your connection...
######################################################################## 100.0%
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p392 to /Users/Family/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p392
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #extracted to /Users/Family/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p392
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #configuring..........
Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/Family/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392 --disable-     install-doc --without-tcl --without-tk --enable-shared',
please read /Users/Family/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p392/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

I am running mac osx Mountan Lion. It dose the same thing if i try to install 1.9.3
What is my problem and how can i fix it? I am new to RVM and ruby so it might be just a simple mistake. Thanks in advance

Comment: I take it you missed where it said `please read /Users/Family/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p392/configure.log`.

Comment: Please post `/Users/Family/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p392/configure.log`?

Comment: here you go `[2013-03-19 21:52:50] ./configure
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --without-tcl, --without-tk
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin12.2.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin12.2.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin12.2.0
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/Users/Family/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p392':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
 ` @hd1

Comment: Install XCode from the App Store

Comment: If this solves your problem, and I suspect it will, let me know, and I'll post it as an answer for others with the same problem.

Comment: do not forget to also post it to https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues so it can be improved - so no manual steps are required - or user is informed about those steps (in case of `Commnad line tools for Xcode` it can not be automated)...

Comment: I already have the latest version of Xcode @hd1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I installed Ruby 2.0 on my OS X Mountain Lion I had to ensure that OpenSSL was first installed. Since I'm using Homebrew, all I had to do a `brew install openssl` before `rvm install 2.0.0`. It looks like you're running Macports (which I haven't used before), so I guess `sudo port install openssl` may work for you.

Also try to install the following as well: `autoconf, automake, libtool, pkg-config, libiconv, libyaml, libffi, readline, libxml2, libxslt, libksba, curl-ca-bundle, sqlite3, zlib, ncurses, gdbm` - they're listed as being missing by the output you've provided.

Answer (score 3):

With the next steps, I installed ruby-2.0.0-rc2 successfully.

```
brew update    
brew install libyaml libxslt sqlite
brew upgrade automake libksba openssl pkg-config
rvm get stable    
rvm autolibs enable
rvm install 2.0.0-p0
```