# Installation of rubygems fails when trying to install Ruby 2.0.0 with RVM

Tags: rvm, osx-mountain-lion, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I'm working on my first Rails app. I just updated from Rails 3.2.13 to Rails 4 and now I was trying to install ruby 2.0.0 but I've been stuck all day getting the same error. I found several questions here on SO and elsewhere, many of them with accepted answers, but simply none of the solutions worked for me.

In the end I ended up completely removing all ruby versions and deleting rvm altogether, but even trying to install it again from scratch results in the same errors. I'm on OSX 10.8.4.

**The error**:

```
Extracting rubygems-2.0.6 ...
Removing old Rubygems files...
Installing rubygems-2.0.6 for ruby-2.0.0-p247......................
Error running 'env GEM_PATH=/Users/arielpontes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247:/Users/arielpontes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global:/Users/arielpontes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247:/Users/arielpontes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global GEM_HOME=/Users/arielpontes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247 /Users/arielpontes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby -d /Users/arielpontes/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/setup.rb',
please read /Users/arielpontes/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p247/1375132582_rubygems.install.log
Installation of rubygems did not complete successfully.
Saving wrappers to '/Users/arielpontes/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p247'...
```

**The logs**:

```
[2013-07-29 18:23:54] /Users/arielpontes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
Exception `LoadError' at /Users/arielpontes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1082 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/operating_system
Exception `LoadError' at /Users/arielpontes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1091 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/ruby
/Users/arielpontes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/yaml.rb:4:in `<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
/Users/arielpontes/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require': dlopen(/Users/arielpontes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.4.0/psych.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib/libyaml-0.2.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/arielpontes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.4.0/psych.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/arielpontes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.4.0/psych.bundle
    from /Users/arielpontes/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
    from /Users/arielpontes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/arielpontes/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
    from /Users/arielpontes/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
    from /Users/arielpontes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/yaml.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/arielpontes/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
    from /Users/arielpontes/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
    from /Users/arielpontes/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems.rb:600:in `load_yaml'
    from /Users/arielpontes/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/config_file.rb:313:in `load_file'
    from /Users/arielpontes/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/config_file.rb:190:in `initialize'
    from /Users/arielpontes/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:66:in `new'
    from /Users/arielpontes/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:66:in `do_configuration'
    from /Users/arielpontes/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:46:in `run'
    from setup.rb:45:in `<main>'
```

Anybody has any idea about what I could do to fix it?? I've tried the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232076/troubles-with-ruby-2-0-0-p0-installation-using-rvm/15233923#15233923) but no avail. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I finally managed to fix it! Sorry if I ended up polluting SO. I'll reply to my question anyway in case somebody runs into similar problems and ends up here in the future.

It turned out I had a messed up installation of `libyaml`, "Installed but not linked", according to Homebrew. I figured it out after trying [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15781083/686617). So I uninstalled `libyaml` and killed it with `sudo rm -rf` and installed it again. I ran into [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449581/brew-install-libyaml-error) but the accepted answer solved it. After this I installed RVM from scratch with stable ruby and it finally worked!

Comment: Whew. Glad I found this. I was banging my head against a wall for a couple hours.